# In matplotlib how to check if an equivalent artist already exist in axes to reduce redundancy?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matploblib figure that would update based on user input. Currently every-time I get new input I would clear the figure then plot the new artist  that comes in. Sometimes the user would plot the same line graph as what it is already on screen and I want to save computation time when this happens by just ignoring the call. I'd prefer not to keep track of previous user input and compare it with the current user input so an "on the fly" comparison function would be appreciated

Comment: Any solution to this would be more complex than keeping track of previous user inputs, so maybe you want to comment why that's not what you want.

Comment: Hmm, it's not really the solution I wanted since there are a lot of variables to keep track and the infrastructure is not there. I assumed that since I already have the axes object and I have the artist I am about to plot there's a way to see if the artist on the axe is equivalent to the thing I am going to plot. But if it's more complex then I will just refactor the code to track user inputs.

Comment: I mean you did not specify anything about the artist that is added; so one cannot know how complex it's really going to be.

Comment: The artist would be a line plot or a scatter plot. Sorry for the lack of specificity, I am not that familiar with matplotlib.artist so my question isn't very targeted. My idea was that the current plot would be visually equivalent to the new plot so it would be nice to be able to do a quick comparison of the underlining parameters before plotting.

Comment: See for example a lineplot and a scatter plot can be visually identical if the lineplot has linestyle="none"; this would mean you would need to check for `Line2D` objects as well as `PathCollection` objects in the axes... or inversely, the same scatter could look totally different depending on which marker has been used, which would require to compare the PathCollection's marker path to each other... That all seems pretty complicated

Comment: You don't specify how your users interact with matplotlib (e.g. jupyter? wxpython?), making this a very broad question. It might e.g. be possible to define a `userInputDidActuallyChange=0` boolean and only update the figure if it's `true`, but that is depending on your actual setup, and might be -- as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said -- quite complicated. Seriously consider how often this edge case may occur, and how complicated your plot actually is. Right now (without specifics!), this rather sounds like a problem where you invest hours of coding to save ~10s compute time.